# BootstrapVue <b-tabs> in a nuxt.js app is displaying contents of all tabs instead of just the active tab

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I created a test `nuxt.js` app with [`BootstrapVue`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs). I used `<b-tabs>`, but instead of contents of just the active tab, contents of all tabs are displayed on the page.

I have the `<b-tabs>` like this:

```html
<template>
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs card >
      <b-tab active title="A" no-body /><p>Content A</p></b-tab>
      <b-tab title="B" no-body /><p>Content B</p></b-tab>
      <b-tab title="C" no-body /><p>Content C</p></b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</template>
```

Regardless of which tab is selected, the page displays all the contents, like this:

> Content A
>
> Content B
>
> Content C

However, if I remove the `<p></p>` tags from the above code, there are subtle differences in how the contents is displayed.

For first tab:

> Content A Content B Content C

For second tab:

> Content A
>
> Content B Content C

For third tab:

> Content A Content B
>
> Content C

What can be the cause of this? I have used BootstrapVue in 'plain' Vue.js app and I didn't have such issues. I don't see anything in the docs either about any required styling.

Comment: Do other bootstrap components work or is it only this one that is buggy? Do you have a [repro] of this?

Comment: That code is the whole `index.vue` file in the root of `pages`. There's nothing else there. The project was created automatically by the npx create-nuxt-app. I didn't try other bootstrap components - this is just a test app, I'm learning nuxt.

Comment: I pasted some example components from bootstrap docs and they seem to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it on my side, it was essentially an issue with tags closing.

```html
<template>
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs card>
      <b-tab active title="A" no-body><p>Content A</p></b-tab>
      <b-tab title="B" no-body><p>Content B</p></b-tab>
      <b-tab title="C" no-body><p>Content C</p></b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</template>
```

Try to use ESlint, it can greatly help you spot bugs in no time!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm blind. I do have eslint, but it underlined just a single `<` in each line and did not throw warning/error, so I guess I missed it, especially that syntax errors usually result in failure to compile.

Comment: @Eggon yeah, here it was sneaky enough to be okay for a compilation haha.